# SQL code in php that Inner Joins a ordered query, with a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, I needed to display all the posts posted, along with the username of the person who posted it. I made an Inner Join between two tables with the "user.id" in common, so that it could display the username aswell.It did the work, however, my teacher asked me to order the posts by "updated_at" time.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN microposts ON users.id = microposts.user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ".mysqli_error($db), E_USER_ERROR);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $posts[$i] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

This is the code that works, and displays the posts and Inner Joins the two tables I needed.

```
$ordered  = "SELECT * FROM microposts ORDER BY updated_at DESC";
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM $ordered INNER JOIN users  ON users.id = microposts.user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ".mysqli_error($db), E_USER_ERROR);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $posts[$i] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

This is the code I thought would work, but it does not work.
Any guess about what I could do ? :)

Comment: Put the `ORDER BY updated_at DESC` on to the joined query.

Comment: It doesn't work :/ Do you meant, like this ? 
```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN microposts ORDER BY updated_at DESC ON users.id = microposts.user_id "; 
```

Comment: No, as you wrote previously. `order by` needs to be after the `join` definitions.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html `select`, then columns, then `from` then table, then possible `join` and `on`s for join relationship, then `where`, then ..., THEN `order`.

Comment: It's working now :) Thx !!

Comment: Working Code : "$query  = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN microposts ON users.id = microposts.user_id ORDER BY microposts.updated_at DESC;"